# UIAlertController gives error while produce alertview

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am getting this error while produce alert view "Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!".
Please look at my code below. I am using operation queue to perform task for alert.

```
class AlertOperation: ASOperation {
    // MARK: Properties

    fileprivate let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    fileprivate let presentationContext: UIViewController?

    var title: String? {
        get {
            return alertController.title
        }

        set {
            alertController.title = newValue
            name = newValue
        }
    }

    var message: String? {
        get {
            return alertController.message
        }

        set {
            alertController.message = newValue
        }
    }    

    // MARK: Initialization
    init(presentationContext: UIViewController? = nil) {
        self.presentationContext = presentationContext ?? UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

        super.init()

        addCondition(AlertPresentation())
        /*
            This operation modifies the view controller hierarchy.
            Doing this while other such operations are executing can lead to
            inconsistencies in UIKit. So, let's make them mutally exclusive.
        */
        addCondition(MutuallyExclusive<UIViewController>())
    }

    func addAction(_ title: String, style: UIAlertActionStyle = .default, handler: @escaping (AlertOperation) -> Void = { _ in }) {
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: style) { [weak self] _ in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                handler(strongSelf)
            }
            self?.finish()
        }

        alertController.addAction(action)
    }

    override func execute() {
        guard let presentationContext = presentationContext else {
            finish()
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.alertController.actions.isEmpty {
                self.addAction("OK")
            }
            presentationContext.present(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

For the first time its working fine but if I press cancel button on alert than its give me above error. Currently I am opening another alert from the same function if user press cancel button.

```
    final func finish(_ errors: [NSError] = []) {
    if !hasFinishedAlready {
        hasFinishedAlready = true
        state = .finishing

        let combinedErrors = _internalErrors + errors
        finished(combinedErrors)

        for observer in observers {
            observer.operationDidFinish(self, errors: combinedErrors)
        }

        state = .finished
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an operation? Are you also able to format your code, please? Thanks.

Comment: Format?, what you means

Comment: I will do it for you. But next time, please do it yourself.

Comment: @LorenzoB ok Thanks. Next time i will do it surely.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to call the initialization of your `AlertOperation` instance with a  ViewController that is not part of the window hieararchy and you are trying to present your alert from that. Please include the code where you create an instance of your `AlertOperation` class and try to present it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor ok. Do i need to create instance as Alertopeation instead of UIViewController. Please correct

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: @SandeepChaudhary without including the requested piece of code, it is really hard to help.

Comment: ok let me put some code here.

Comment: find the top vc != nil present in topvc, else present in self

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  do i nee to check nill for presentationContext?

Comment: Where is cancel button Alert ? , How you are handling cancel event ?. Are you finishing operation on cancel action ?

Comment: That's why. You are showing alertcontroller from alertcontroller. Either your operation doesn't finish or you are not showing alert after dismissing current showing alert.

Comment: @MikeAlter i am finishing operation. look at this     final func finish(_ errors: [NSError] = []) {
        if !hasFinishedAlready {
            hasFinishedAlready = true
            state = .finishing
            
            let combinedErrors = _internalErrors + errors
            finished(combinedErrors)
            
            for observer in observers {
                observer.operationDidFinish(self, errors: combinedErrors)
            }
            
            state = .finished
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is some issue with your `presentationContext`, i.e. if its view is present in the window hierarchy,

For this try replacing

```
presentationContext.present(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(self.alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If it works with presenting it on `window's` `rootViewController`, then try resolving your `presentationContext`.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of a response. It does not provide any added value.